# AngularJS $location.path looping back to root

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I've looked everywhere, but none of the potential solutions have worked.

The sign-in page is supposed to route to the tabs page upon a successful login or registration. For some reason it is directing back to the root, or `otherwise` state every time. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

States:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('intro', {
url: '/intro',
templateUrl: 'templates/intro.html',
controller: 'IntroCtrl'
})
 .state('signin', {
  url: '/sign-in',
  templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
  controller: 'SignInCtrl'
})
.state('forgotpassword', {
  url: '/forgot-password',
  templateUrl: 'templates/forgot-password.html'
})
.state('tabs', {
  url: '/tab',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})
.state('tabs.home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
    }
  }
});


 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/intro');

})
```

Controller that should route to the tabs page upon login:

```
  .controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state, $firebaseAuth, $location) {

$scope.login = function(username, password) {
    var fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(fb);
    fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
        email: username,
        password: password
    }).then(function(authData) {
        $location.path('/tab')
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("ERROR: " + error);
    });
}

$scope.register = function(username, password) {
    var fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(fb);
    fbAuth.$createUser({email: username, password: password}).then(function() {
        return fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
            email: username,
            password: password
        });
    }).then(function(authData) {
        $location.path("/tab");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("ERROR " + error);
    });
}
})
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$state.go('tabs')` instead of the `$location` service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ui-router and state-based routing, simply call `$state.go()` for quick navigation between states. Note - you'll likely need to either remove `abstract: true` from your `tabs` state or transition to `tabs.home`. For example...

```
.then(function(authData) {
     // $location.path('/tab');
     $state.go('tabs')
})
```

See the [documentation - $state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) for more information

> Convenience method for transitioning to a new state